# Why aren't my variables recognized when set in the markup?

Tags: asp.net

Why isn't `someDate` and `amount` recognized at run-time?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <% 
        decimal amount = 10.0m;
        DateTime someDate = new DateTime(2018, 12, 25);
    %>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"><%= amount %></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%= someDate %></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because they are out of scope. Declare the variables in the code behind file if you are going to use them with Controls.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you're going to do "standalone" (aka "inline") `aspx` pages which means there is no code-behind:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script runat="server" language="c#">
        decimal amount = 10.0m;
        DateTime someDate = new DateTime(2018, 12, 25);
    </script>
</head>
```